# anaconda spyder sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I've run into a problem running Spyder that I can't seem to resolve.  Any help would be appreciated.

I've been using Anaconda Spyder on Windows 7 without much trouble.  I had to do a hard shut down of my computer while Spyder was running.  When I turned it back on, Spyder loads with the error while starting the kernel: "sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed".  The first few lines of the specific error are

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\***\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\history.py", line 87, in catch_corrupt_db
return f(self, *a, **kw)
File "C:\***\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\history.py", line 257, in init_db
end timestamp, num_cmds integer, remark text)""")
sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed
```

Following this there is a list of other exceptions which occurred but I imagine they are related to these first lines.

I've tried checking SQlite3 using `PRAGMA integrity_check` but it did not return any errors.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda but the problem persists.

I've spent a number of hours over many days trying various fixes in online forums but can't seem to figure out the one that works for me.

I'd really appreciate some guidance, thanks

Comment: I think you need to remove your `.ipython` directory to fix this problem. It should be directly under your personal `Users` directory.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, thank you, yes, that was the issue.  Unfortunately, the `.ipython` directory was not in the personal `Users` directory and needed to be found.

Comment: Ok, glad you finally fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to work through the problem with a colleague and the solution was to delete the files contained in the IPython Profile Directory.  When the kernel was restarted, it recreated the needed files in the directory and Spyder was back to a usable state.

**Test to see if this method might work:**

Open the IPython prompt and try running `ipython` command.  This gave me the same error as was given in Spyder this led us to the conclusion that it is an IPython issue, since Spyder references the IPython profile.

Create a temp directory somewhere convenient, go back to the IPython prompt, and change the IPython Profile Directory to the temp directory you created.  You can do this by entering `ipython --ipython-dir=<path>` which is outlined here: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/intro.html#ipythondir.  Note that for windows you would enter something like `ipython --ipython-dir=C:\tempFolder`.  Again run `IPython`.  You should now be in a python script and if you check the tempFolder, you'll see that it has created new folders inside it.

**How to correct the issue:**

The profile directory can be found by opening Spyder, going to Tools → Preferences, then in the pop-up window go to the "Profiler" tab.  The directory is listed on the right side of the pop-up window.

You then must go to that directory and delete the folders contained inside it.  In my case, there were 3 folders.  In Spyder, go to Consoles → Restart Kernel.